# How can I have two rows of multiple columns for subplots

Tags: python, subplot

The following code generates the image below with one row of several images.
I would like to add another row below or above the current row containing another series of images in `test` array, which is similar to `predict` array. I tried several numbers for the subplots, like 2 instead of 1, but it just gives an error or doesn't work.  if I replace 1 with 2 it gives the error `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'matshow'` for the 4th line, which seems irrelevant!

Could you please guide me what should I do?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, len(predict), figsize=(10, 5))
fig.suptitle('Output Data with bias term {0}'.format(b))
for i in range(len(predict)):
    ax[i].matshow(predict[i].reshape((n_units, n_units)), cmap='gray')
    ax[i].set_xticks([])
    ax[i].set_yticks([])
plt.show('{0:02d}'.format(b))
```

[image]

Comment: `fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, len(predict)//2, figsize=(10, 5))`?

Comment: @QuangHoang No, if I replace 2 it gives error `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'matshow'` for the 4th line.

Comment: `ax` then is a `2 x n` array, you need to access its elements by `ax[r][c]` not just `ax[i]`

Comment: @QuangHoang Bingo! you can write your comment as an answer, if you wish!